# How to Get the tag value of JSON response in a http request

Tags: ios, iphone

I have to make 10 different http post method to server, and I'm doing this asynchronously. but my success of failure response will hit to same method. but if some request fails of time out i want to know which http cal has failed, is this possible to track. And how to get the tag value for the response.

Comment: can you show your tried code , it is easy to optimize the answer

Comment: @Anbu you said right.